# how to tabulate 2 ndarrays of floats in python without rounding

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working with bumpy and matplotlib. I have 2 ndarrays that I wish to produce a table containing 2 column to compare them side by side

How can I compare the without rounding the values? I have tried [the table function](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.table.html), but it would store each digit in a single cell when I pass in type casted floats

```
    #my code
the_table = plt.table(cellText= str(w), #w is a float
                          rowLabels= None,
                          colLabels="columns",
                          loc='bottom')
        plt.show()
```

My table looks like this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzQxy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table` expects sequences of numbers, each of which goes into a single table cell. You give it only the string representation of a single number, so interprets each character in this string as the content for a single cell.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.random.randn(20)  # data for first column
b = np.random.randn(20)  # data for second column
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis("off")
ax.table(cellText=np.column_stack([a,b]),loc="center")
plt.show()
```

gives

[image]

Note that there is still some amount of rounding. To avoid that you might have to handle the float-to-string conversion yourself (for example, using `repr`).

Does the table have to be a matplotlib plot? It would be much easier to just use something like

```
for x, y in zip(a,b):
    print "{}\t{}".format(repr(x),repr(y))
```